# Async for loop Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make the loop run before the `console.log` but the first thing that runs is the `console.log`

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("hello " + i); 
    }, 500);
}

console.log("Bye bye");
```

Comment: Remove `setTimeout(..)` !!!, that will always wait for the time provided (500 in your case) to pass before it runs code inside it. That's how async set timeout works buddy. Try to learn more about how event loop and async things are handled in node js and you will find the answer to your own question.

Comment: the loop does run first, but it completes before 500ms

Comment: This is a simple example unlike what I am doing

Answer (score 1):

Because most of the function in javascript are asynchronous (most known are `Promises`, `setTimeout` and `setInterval`) to avoid blocking the flow execution, the loop does not wait the `setTimeout` function to continue its execution.

You can do something like that by using an `async/await` function which will wait to resolve the promise before continuing, be careful with [the setTimeout in loop](https://coderwall.com/p/_ppzrw/be-careful-with-settimeout-in-loops) (it's not something recommended)

If you want to achieve that, you can do the following:

```js
;(async () => { // Declaration to make the code async

  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function(){ 
          console.log("hello " + i); 
          resolve();
      }, 500));
  }

  console.log("Bye bye");
})();
```

Comment: "*Because javascript is an asynchronous language*" it is not asynchronious. There are *some* async operations but most of the code runs synchronously and is deterministic. `x = 1; x += 2; y = x + 3` will always evaluate in the same order.

Comment: Good one, I should have precise that the function can be asynchronous to not block the code flow, updated